# Shut down acts as restart?

Tags: live-usb, power-management, shutdown, acer, reboot

I've installed Ubuntu (almost all latest versions), when my Acer Aspire V5-471 is *want to shutdown from Ubuntu*, it **acts as restart/reboot.** Refer to *edit 2* for releases tried and *edit 1* for tried derivatives.

*edit 1:* It's happens on 2 versions (till now), Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio/Xubuntu (both Ubuntu-studio and XFCE session).

*edit 2:* Same as *edit 1* (only for live-user, others only uses Ubuntu), happened on Normal installation (12.04 to 13.04), Wubi installation (12.04 only), and Live User Session (12.04 to 13.04).

Rebooted after short shutdown time even as `root` or `sudo`-ing from this command :

`shutdown -h now`

Why? Can I fix this?

Comment: Can you tell us what is actually happening? So what do you do to start the "shutdown", what do you see on your screen, etc. YOu can also check your syslog for messages.

Comment: Not enough information is provided. There is a translucent popup right? Which did you click?

Comment: @owl I just click shutdown.

Comment: @AryoAdhiWibisonoLegopermono What about you do 'sudo shutdown -h' on Terminal?

Comment: I'll try it... i'll recomment if that successfull

Comment: I experience this on my Lenovo T430s too, however only sometimes. I could not find any pattern when it happens.

Comment: I encounter the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the mainline 3.9 kernel appears to solve it.

[See here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/ready-for-linux-kernel-3-9-install-upgrade-your-kernel-in-ubuntu-13-04/) for installation direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is true in Debian, I assume the same is true in Ubuntu.

`shutdown` takes arguments in order to achieve specific events.  I guess in Ubuntu, they made the default for `shutdown` an alias to `shutdown -r now` (`-r` for restart, now for, well, now).  If you want to halt the system, or shutdown, do `shutdown -h now` (`-h` for halt) and that should do what you want.

Comment: tried and keeps reboot... running as root

Comment: shutdown -h now does?  Perhaps the above user is correct then, the -h switch should never cause a reboot, that should be a halt

Comment: I don't know what's happening on my notebook, and it's always REBOOT even running it as root or `sudo`-ing first... Going to record and upload to YouTube.

Comment: According to [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=118094) from the Mint forums which should be running the same base, this is due to a Wake on LAN error, try disabling your wireless in the BIOS and then rebooting and try it again.  According to them shutdown works fine, but WoL is triggering a power on as soon as you shut down, making it seem like a reboot.

Comment: Already disabled, but won't shutdown. I think it's hardware-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

No its not hardware specific problem, it happens on my 3 laptops with different hw.
I even just upgrade kernel to 3.16 but it still happens.
The only way i found to actually shutdown, is before shutdown your computer just disable wlan0, then shutdown normally and voila. but on next start you will have to activate it again. 
BTW:- Antix, Neptuno, Debian KDE and Arch, can shutdown my laptops with out problem, and using 3.13.xx kernel. So i think the issue is not in the kernel.

Slackware, Ubuntu (K,X,L,S), Mint (C, M, K), Fedora cant shutdown, just reboot.
I didnt try LMDE yet, but as is Debian Based, im just wondering it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `shutdown` command does not work if wake on lan is enabled in the bios. If you have to use wake on lan use `halt -p` instead of `shutdown`.

Alternatively you can use the following to shutdown your system

```
sudo poweroff
```